# my app freez and show error your Content Must have listview

Tags: java, android

i want to retrieve data from sqllite data base when i click on category my app freez and show error your content must have listView whose id is R.id.list here is my logcat report
first i click on category report button it display listview in list view i click on category name like "Food" and that food string text is pass by intent to another activity where it save to cursor and pass an argumnt to method to call

```
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
activity ComponentInfo{com.exmang/com.exmang.ShowCat}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is  
'android.R.id.list'
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at   
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at  
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-28 18:48:26.168: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
```

here is my database table declaration

```
public static final String EX_RowID = "_id";
public static final String EX_Cattype = "Ecattype";
public static final String EX_Date = "Ecdate";
public static final String EX_Price = "Ecprice";
public static final String EX_Type = "itype";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DataBase";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1 ;
private static final String Food_TABLE = "FoodTable";

private DbHelper ourhelper;
private final Context ourcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourdatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Food_TABLE +"(" +
                EX_RowID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                EX_Cattype + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                EX_Date + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                EX_Price + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                EX_Type + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);"
                );
```

here is the method that call the string value contain the text of each category that will be equal to desired columns

```
//return category wise data in listview
public Cursor CategExpData(String value) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String[] columns = new String[] {EX_RowID,EX_Cattype, EX_Date, EX_Price, EX_Type };
Cursor c= ourdatabase.query(Food_TABLE, columns, EX_Cattype + "='" + value + "'",  
null, null, null, null);
if (c != null) {

       c.moveToFirst();

      }
return c;

}
```

here is the listview to appear when i click on listview item the desire text item of list view is pass to another activity whe

```
public class Catrpt extends ListActivity {

String myexpenselist[] = {"Food", "Medical" ,"Education",  
"Shopping","Entertainment",
        "Bills", "Automobiles", "Travel"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Catrpt.this, 
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myexpenselist));

}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Object o = l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String str_text = o.toString();
    //Log.i("lsr", str_text.toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(Catrpt.this, ShowCat.class);
    intent.putExtra("StrValue", str_text);
    Log.i("lsr2", str_text.toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}


 }
```

Now in the below class the desired data is save to cursor where it match also in the database method to desired column in the below activity my logcat show the desired value correct where i set and also in this class i have error on line **setContentView(R.layout.myelst); this and ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);// Assign adapter to ListView**

```
public class ShowCat extends ListActivity {
    private ExMgDB CatDb;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myelst);

        CatDb = new ExMgDB(this);
        CatDb.open();
        displayListView();
        CatDb.close();
    }
    private void displayListView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("StrValue").toString();
        Log.i("lsrval", value.toString());
        Cursor cursor = CatDb.CategExpData(value);
        Log.i("Mytagcrsr", cursor.toString());
        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[] {
            ExMgDB.EX_RowID,
            ExMgDB.EX_Cattype,
            ExMgDB.EX_Date,
            ExMgDB.EX_Price,
            ExMgDB.EX_Type
        };

        Log.i("Mytagcat", columns.toString());

        int[] to =  new int[]{
            R.id.txtexid,
            R.id.txtexcat,
            R.id.txtexdate,
            R.id.txtexprice,
            R.id.txtexitype
        };
        Log.i("Mytagto", to.toString());
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this, R.layout.emtolst, 
                    cursor, 
                    columns, 
                    to,
                    0);

        Log.i("Mytagadap", cursor.toString());

        ListView listView = (ListView) 
        findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        Log.i("lsttag", listView.toString());
    }
}
```

here is myelst xml file that display the data in listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is emtolst xml file that use in display data in listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/foodtablelayout"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingRight="90dp"
    android:text="ID: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:text="Category Type: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
      android:paddingRight="72dp"
      android:text="Date: "
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:paddingRight="95dp"
    android:text="Price: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtexprice"
    android:paddingRight="60dp"
    android:text="Item Type: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtexid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="TextView" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtexcat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtexdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtexprice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtexitype"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: so do what the error says change your listview id to `android.r.id.list`

Comment: which xml you are using in Catrpt activity?

Comment: in this class no xml file i create the listview by java code by default

Comment: still same error exist sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the xml file, change the id of ListView to "@android:id/list". The program will work fine. Hope it helped. :)

Comment: sorry i change it but still same error exist......

Comment: thanks sir it work now i change it exactly....but now how can i accept you question when i want to accept it it need reputation\